# Why the $\Delta$ in the definition of pressure? (fluid mechanics)

Tags: classical-mechanics, pressure, differentiation, fluid-statics, notation

I'm an engineering student (first year) studying Physics 1 (now an introduction to fluid mechanics).

**Q1**

In my physics textbook, the "medium pressure" is defined as:
$$p_m = \frac{\Delta F_{\perp}}{\Delta S}$$
and, intuitively, the "pressure in a point" is defined as:
$$p = \frac{dF_{\perp}}{dS}$$
Regardless if the form it's written in, I cannot understand the meaning of putting a $\Delta$ in front of $F_{\perp}$: usually, we used $\Delta X$ to mean $X_2 - X_1$ for some physical quantity $X$, but here instead it seems to me that we mean:

- For $\Delta F_\perp$, really just a perpendicular force $F_\perp$
- For $\Delta S$, we mean a portion of a surface $S$

**Q2**

In a similar way, what is the meaning of the $\Delta$ in the definition of "medium density"? $$\rho_m = \frac{\Delta m}{\Delta V}$$
It seems to me that, in a similar way, $\Delta m$ just means "the mass $m$ of a portion of the volume $V$".

**NOTE**

My question derives also from the fact that, apparently for me, there is no reason to add the "differential" $d$ in these definitions, but all the equations work with this "differential form" (and probably wouldn't have sense/work in other forms)

Comment: You have two answers to your **Q1**. Regarding **Q2**, I've never met the equation you quote. The mean density of the material forming a body of mass $m$ and volume $V$ is just $\rho=m/V$. If we add to the body an extra piece of material we could reasonably denote the mass of the extra material by $\Delta m$ and its volume by $\Delta V$, so the density of the extra material would be $\Delta m/\Delta V$. If the material is homogeneous, then $m/V=\Delta m/\Delta V$. But I see no advantage in defining $\rho$ in terms of the incremental quantities or the derivative $dm/dt$.

Comment: @PhilipWood thanks, but I repeat to you the question I asked to mikestone: how is it possible that someone can get the same results (while, for example, proving theorems) with both versions the definitions, one with the $d$ of the differential, one without? I don’t know why, but this confuses me a lot

Comment: It's because, as I said, if the material is homogeneous then the density of an extra bit of material (mass $\Delta m$, volume $\Delta V$) added to the body is the same as the density of the material already in the body, so $\Delta m/ \Delta V=m/V$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $\Delta$ is there to indicate that it is the "bit" of the total force on the boundary due to the pressure pushing on the *small* area $\Delta S$.

$P= \Delta F/\Delta S$ is better written as a vector equation
$$
\Delta {\bf F} = P \,{\bf n} \,\Delta S
$$
where $F$ is the force on a small area $\Delta S$ of the fluid boundary.,  ${\bf n}$ is the  unit normal vector to the small area pointing from the fluid into the boundary.

Comment: Thanks, but it’s still not very clear to me, then, why many other sources just define $P=F/A$ (I used $A$ in this case to indicate the surface). In general, force shouldn’t depend from the area it’s applied to, so why should we take a “small bit” of it? Where am I mistaken? And how is it possible that someone can get the same results (while, for example, proving theorems) with both versions the definitions, one with the $d$ of the differential, one without?

Comment: See the answer by @Farcher below.

Answer (score 3):

*Pressure is the amount of force applied perpendicular to the surface of an object per unit area.*

A problem arises when the surface is not flat ie curved.

So what is done is to take an infinitesimally small element of the surface $dA$ with a clearly definable normal $\hat n$ and then define pressure $P$ via the relationship $\vec F= P\,d\vec A = A \,dA\,\hat n$.
With your notation it is assumed that the incremental area  $\Delta A$ is taken to be small enough for the area to be assumed to be flat.